# Error when closing my application in the middle of the loop

Tags: vb.net, do-while

Here is my code for my loop:

```
Do While potsStatus = True
Dim ForeGroundHwnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow
Dim MySearchWinow As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, SearchWindow)
If ForeGroundHwnd = MySearchWinow Then
    If rbQ.Checked = True Then
        keybd_event(vbKeyQ, 0, 0, 0)
        keybd_event(vbKeyQ, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(1)
    ElseIf rbW.Checked = True Then
        keybd_event(vbKeyW, 0, 0, 0)
        keybd_event(vbKeyW, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(1)
    ElseIf rbE.Checked = True Then
        keybd_event(vbKeyE, 0, 0, 0)
        keybd_event(vbKeyE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(1)
    ElseIf rbR.Checked = True Then
        keybd_event(vbKeyR, 0, 0, 0)
        keybd_event(vbKeyR, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(1)
    End If
End If
```

The problem is when the loop is running and I exit/close the application it encounters errors, the process remains and the loop never ends. The only thing I can do is to manually stop the process in Task Manager. I hope someone can help me with this.

EDIT: Solved. I made the loop false in the Form Closing event. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop unless you provide a way postStatus to become false inside the loop it would be running forever.

Comment: Pretty hard to tell without knowing tha actual errors. Can you provide them?

Comment: Why don't you use an event handler on the search window to do this? Now your application is burning a lot of CPU cycles for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code I can't see anywhere that you set `potsStatus` to false (on an aside you don't need to say `Do While potsStatus = True`, you can just say `Do While potsStatus`). What you need to do is have some mechanism for letting your loop know that it needs to stop.

So on your form close event you could set `potsStatus` to false (assuming it is a form wide variable). This kind of looks like it would be a good `Thread` candidate although without having a better idea of the code I can't say for sure.